Is encoding required to properly store any Unicode character in a PostgreSQL database, using sequelize in typescript?
I have a typescript project which connects via sequelize to a PostgreSQL database. All string columns in all tables in the database are TEXT type, which as per PostgreSQL documentation, support Unicode characters. We will need to allow characters of multiple languages to be stored in those columns.
The current LC_CTYPE and LC_COLLATE are set to English_United States.1252, and I have manually created records using multiple different characters, and they all are stored correctly. However, I am not sure this will work when creating those records not from the database, but from the typescript project. I cannot currently check, since our environments are having third-party issues at the moment, and I couldn't find any documentation about it. One coworker mentioned we might need to investigate about needing encoding in our typescript backend, but my question is, is that true? If so, should we encode every string we send to the database via sequelize to UTF8?

The important part is that you set the database encoding correctly, that is to UTF-8. You can test that with
SHOW server_encoding;

 server_encoding 
═════════════════
 UTF8
(1 row)

If you get anything else, you won't be able to store all characters, and you have to create a new database with the proper encoding (the database encoding cannot be changed).
What you co-worker probably meant is that you should set the client encoding correctly: it has to match the character encoding that your Typescript application uses internally. To set the PostgreSQL client encoding, set the parameter client_encoding to the correct value in your database session.
